# How to remove KDE plasma?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, unity

Recently I have installed KDE desktop on my Ubuntu 14.04. then I wanted to uninstall it. I tried everything [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451620/how-to-completely-remove-kubuntu-desktop-from-ubuntu) but no use. I can still login to KDE. The worst part is even in unity so many things are messed up e.g. It changed the text color of menu same as bg (I cant read anything), changed icons etc.

How can I completely removing KDE and clean up this mess?